# How to show or hide query results based on specifc date?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have all records in a single table.  I only want to see records for any user if they don't have a record with a date >= 2017-01-01 in the DATE field.

So if say there are multiple records for user A:

```
RID   USER    DATE
1       A      2015-01-01  
2       A      2016-01-01
3       A      2017-01-01
```

Since there is a record with a date >= 2017-01-01, then I do NOT want to see ANY of the records for user A.

If RID 3 above with the date >=2017-01-01 did not exist, then I want to see any or all the other records for user A, namely RID 1&2.

I have no clue!

Sorry here is all the my code that does not work, it still shows all the records for those who have date >= '2017-01-01', it just does not show the records for which they have the date >= 2017-01-01.  I don't want to see ANY of there records if they have a record with a date >= 2017-01-01:

```
select t.*, t2.*, T3.*
from t
left outer join t2 on t.id = t2.id
left outer join t3 on t3.id = t2.id
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.user = t.user and t2.date >= '2017-01-01'
                 )
and t3.name = 'abc'
and t2.status = 'con'
and (t.note like '%true%' or t.note like '%false%')
order by 1,2
```

Thanks,

MP

Comment: in SQL think of data in terms of sets.  So you have a set of data for all users and their dates.  Then you want a set of data for all users with a record date >= 2017-01-01.  and then what you want is all users from the 1st set who are (not in) (not exists)  (with no record in (left join 1st to 2nd where user is null in 2nd set)    https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ offers some guidance on join types.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.user = t.user and t2.date >= '2017-01-01'
                 );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply!  I tried that but not working.  I have two inner joins in the mix, could they be messing it up?  I still get results showing that have  records with a date >= 2017-01-01.  ???

Comment: @mrpush Add the whole query to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the original post with all my code.  Thanks.

Comment: Still no luck, it lists all the records just eliminating the ones with the date >=2017-01-01.  I Want to exclude ALL USER RECORDS if ANY records have the date >=2017-01-01 in them.  I believe the solution given is just getting rid of the ones withthe date in them.  how can I have it hide all records for a specific user ID if ANY records for the user have the date in them?

Comment: @mrpush . . . This question should remove any user that has a date since 2017-01-01.  That is what `not exists` does with the correlation clause.